# network traffic monitor over time

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, network-monitoring

I am running an ubuntu server 16 and are looking to use an application that runs as a daemon collecting network traffic stats over time (day/week/month) and displays it in some form.

I should be able to breakdown the traffic by either subnet/IP or protocol

ntop (opensource version) hasn't been updated since 2012 and using it seem to have a few bugs.

vnstat is the closes i have found but it dosent let me break down the traffic by IP/protocol

thanks
alexis

Comment: `Sysstat` is the closest one that I'm aware of... worth to check out I guess.

Comment: @Ravexina thanks for the suggestion. That tool seem to have quite a brutal learning curve (for me at least). I had a look at the doc and tutorial    http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/ but can't seem to find anything regarding how to monitor network traffic. Would you have any links that may help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running webmin and it have a bandwidth monitor that logs traffic thru iptables and then summaries it in a neat log.

Look at print
https://i.stack.imgur.com/muzXq.jpg

Comment: from the image I can see that it shows the total bandwidth for each day. Is it possible to pick a day and get a breakdown of the total bandwidth to a specific IP address?

Comment: You can sort by port/host/internal port if you like.
Heres the docs for it
https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Bandwidth_Monitoring